# System-wide hotkey for custom text field highlighting

Tags: windows, text, selection, highlighting

I want to create a way of enabling my computer to highlight text in any given text field, of any application, *as I type it*. The idea is I would press a hotkey and that would cause all text typed after pressing that hotkey to be highlighted until I press the hotkey again. What technologies, if any, could achieve this on a Windows XP or Windows 7 machine? And where do the current text selection behaviors such "live" (e.g. selection using shift+arrow keys, and deselection on key press, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exceedingly unlikely that you could achieve this.

You can use `RegisterHotKey` and keyboard hooks to intercept the hot key and subsequent typing. That's not too bad.

What you won't be able to manage is to arrange that the text you type will appear highlighted.  You'd have to special case many of the target applications. Applications like web browsers often don't use windowed controls for their input fields. There's no easy way to highlight the text as it is typed into those fields.

Your question used terms like "system-wide" and "any given text field". That's just not a realistic goal. Making this work for a single class of fields in a certain apps sounds more plausible. You may be able to do it when the text is going to land in a windowed edit control. Although even that sounds fraught with potential threading conflicts. You may also be able to make some headway with apps that support UIautomation, but again it doesn't seem like it would be very easy and many apps don't support UIautomation.

Comment: Thanks David, that was kind of what I expected. I used "system-wide" under the (probably incorrect) assumption that text field behavior all stemmed from a central location like a single Windows assembly. It's just a feature I wish was already available just like pressing ctrl+shift+arrow keys is already (almost everywhere). My end goal was having something you could install to somehow hack this functionality. I obviously would need to do tons of research first as I have no experience with this sort of thing. If I had to settle for less, I could settle for having it in just Visual Studio.

Comment: Any idea on the second question?

Comment: I don't understand the second Q

Comment: I mean what code or files control the existing text selection behavior? If Microsoft were going to include my idea in Windows, what would they edit?